# Invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double *')

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this method inside a Card class. What I want is to subtract values, and below is the method I've created. However, it gives me the error as stated at this post's title. Below is the line by which the error points to.

```
latestPoints = ([self.points doubleValue] - requiredPoints);
```

How should I go about with this? I've seen posts like this saying the same error, however I didn't find anything that can be of value to what I want to do.

Advice please.

Card.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Card : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *points;

- (double) subtractPoints: (double *) requiredPoints;

@end
```

Card.m

```
#import "Card.h"

@implementation Card

@synthesize points = _points;


- (double) subtractPoints:(double *)requiredPoints
{

    double latestPoints;

    latestPoints = ([self.points doubleValue] - requiredPoints);

    return latestPoints;
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you mean for requiredPoints to be double* not double?

Comment: I do not know anything about ovjective-c, so I may be wrong here, but isnt the error quite self-explanatory? requiredPoints is a pointer. To use the value stored in it, you should first de-reference it. I mean use it with a "double" value.

Comment: @rdelmar is right - you need to change the (double *) argument type to (double).  Doubles are primitive types and are passed by value.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) this one's OK now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using double pointer to pass a double value. Or are you trying to pass a double array? Either way

```
latestPoints = ([self.points doubleValue] - *requiredPoints);
```

will do the work for you. If it is an array (single dimensional) *requiredPoints will get you the first value in array

EDIT: Also if you are trying to pass a single double value, no need to use pointer.

```
- (double) subtractPoints:(double)requiredPoints
```

is enough. and call it as

```
[yourObject substractPoints:your_double_value];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just removed the * in the (double *) requiredPoints and it now works :)

Comment: @Grauzten from your question it seems your understanding of pointers is very limited. If you are a want to be objective C developer take some time to learn C pointers and usage. All the best

Comment: Quite new to the language that's why. Yep2 I want to, I'd do what you've suggested. If there were some helpful links you know, may I humbly request for some. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `double*` to `double` in your method definition of `subtractPoints` and it should work.

The reason this is failing is because you are subtracting a pointer from a `double` value. Another option would be to dereference your `requiredPoints` argument in the subtraction. However, I see no reason why you would want to provide the `double` as a pointer type to your subtraction method.